# How to load and predict with a tensorflow model saved from save_weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am running a fairly customized tensorflow model from the following repo:

https://github.com/strongio/keras-bert/blob/master/keras-bert.py

```html
# Initialize session
sess = tf.Session()


# # Load all files from a directory in a DataFrame.
# def load_directory_data(directory):
#     data = {}
#     data["sentence"] = []
#     data["sentiment"] = []
#     for file_path in os.listdir(directory):
#         with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(directory, file_path), "r") as f:
#             data["sentence"].append(f.read())
#             data["sentiment"].append(re.match("\d+_(\d+)\.txt", file_path).group(1))
#     return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


# # Merge positive and negative examples, add a polarity column and shuffle.
# def load_dataset(directory):
#     pos_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "pos"))
#     neg_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "neg"))
#     pos_df["polarity"] = 1
#     neg_df["polarity"] = 0
#     return pd.concat([pos_df, neg_df]).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)


# # Download and process the dataset files.
# def download_and_load_datasets(force_download=False):
#     dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
#         fname="aclImdb.tar.gz",
#         origin="http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz",
#         extract=True,
#     )

#     train_df = load_dataset(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), "aclImdb", "train"))
#     test_df = load_dataset(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), "aclImdb", "test"))

#     return train_df, test_df


class PaddingInputExample(object):
    """Fake example so the num input examples is a multiple of the batch size.
  When running eval/predict on the TPU, we need to pad the number of examples
  to be a multiple of the batch size, because the TPU requires a fixed batch
  size. The alternative is to drop the last batch, which is bad because it means
  the entire output data won't be generated.
  We use this class instead of `None` because treating `None` as padding
  battches could cause silent errors.
  """


class InputExample(object):
    """A single training/test example for simple sequence classification."""

    def __init__(self, guid, text_a, text_b=None, label=None):
        """Constructs a InputExample.
    Args:
      guid: Unique id for the example.
      text_a: string. The untokenized text of the first sequence. For single
        sequence tasks, only this sequence must be specified.
      text_b: (Optional) string. The untokenized text of the second sequence.
        Only must be specified for sequence pair tasks.
      label: (Optional) string. The label of the example. This should be
        specified for train and dev examples, but not for test examples.
    """
        self.guid = guid
        self.text_a = text_a
        self.text_b = text_b
        self.label = label


def create_tokenizer_from_hub_module(bert_path):
    """Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
    bert_module = hub.Module(bert_path)
    tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
    vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run(
        [tokenization_info["vocab_file"], tokenization_info["do_lower_case"]]
    )

    return FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)


def convert_single_example(tokenizer, example, max_seq_length=256):
    """Converts a single `InputExample` into a single `InputFeatures`."""

    if isinstance(example, PaddingInputExample):
        input_ids = [0] * max_seq_length
        input_mask = [0] * max_seq_length
        segment_ids = [0] * max_seq_length
        label = 0
        return input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label

    tokens_a = tokenizer.tokenize(example.text_a)
    if len(tokens_a) > max_seq_length - 2:
        tokens_a = tokens_a[0 : (max_seq_length - 2)]

    tokens = []
    segment_ids = []
    tokens.append("[CLS]")
    segment_ids.append(0)
    for token in tokens_a:
        tokens.append(token)
        segment_ids.append(0)
    tokens.append("[SEP]")
    segment_ids.append(0)

    input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)

    # The mask has 1 for real tokens and 0 for padding tokens. Only real
    # tokens are attended to.
    input_mask = [1] * len(input_ids)

    # Zero-pad up to the sequence length.
    while len(input_ids) < max_seq_length:
        input_ids.append(0)
        input_mask.append(0)
        segment_ids.append(0)

    assert len(input_ids) == max_seq_length
    assert len(input_mask) == max_seq_length
    assert len(segment_ids) == max_seq_length

    return input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, example.label


def convert_examples_to_features(tokenizer, examples, max_seq_length=256):
    """Convert a set of `InputExample`s to a list of `InputFeatures`."""

    input_ids, input_masks, segment_ids, labels = [], [], [], []
    for example in tqdm(examples, desc="Converting examples to features"):
        input_id, input_mask, segment_id, label = convert_single_example(
            tokenizer, example, max_seq_length
        )
        input_ids.append(input_id)
        input_masks.append(input_mask)
        segment_ids.append(segment_id)
        labels.append(label)
    return (
        np.array(input_ids),
        np.array(input_masks),
        np.array(segment_ids),
        np.array(labels).reshape(-1, 1),
    )


def convert_text_to_examples(texts, labels):
    """Create InputExamples"""
    InputExamples = []
    for text, label in zip(texts, labels):
        InputExamples.append(
            InputExample(guid=None, text_a=" ".join(text), text_b=None, label=label)
        )
    return InputExamples


class BertLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_fine_tune_layers=10,
        pooling="mean",
        bert_path="https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
        self.trainable = True
        self.output_size = 768
        self.pooling = pooling
        self.bert_path = bert_path
        if self.pooling not in ["first", "mean"]:
            raise NameError(
                f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}"
            )

        super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bert = hub.Module(
            self.bert_path, trainable=self.trainable, name=f"{self.name}_module"
        )

        # Remove unused layers
        trainable_vars = self.bert.variables
        if self.pooling == "first":
            trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]
            trainable_layers = ["pooler/dense"]

        elif self.pooling == "mean":
            trainable_vars = [
                var
                for var in trainable_vars
                if not "/cls/" in var.name and not "/pooler/" in var.name
            ]
            trainable_layers = []
        else:
            raise NameError(
                f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}"
            )

        # Select how many layers to fine tune
        for i in range(self.n_fine_tune_layers):
            trainable_layers.append(f"encoder/layer_{str(11 - i)}")

        # Update trainable vars to contain only the specified layers
        trainable_vars = [
            var
            for var in trainable_vars
            if any([l in var.name for l in trainable_layers])
        ]

        # Add to trainable weights
        for var in trainable_vars:
            self._trainable_weights.append(var)

        for var in self.bert.variables:
            if var not in self._trainable_weights:
                self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

        super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
        bert_inputs = dict(
            input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
        )
        if self.pooling == "first":
            pooled = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
                "pooled_output"
            ]
        elif self.pooling == "mean":
            result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
                "sequence_output"
            ]

            mul_mask = lambda x, m: x * tf.expand_dims(m, axis=-1)
            masked_reduce_mean = lambda x, m: tf.reduce_sum(mul_mask(x, m), axis=1) / (
                    tf.reduce_sum(m, axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1e-10)
            input_mask = tf.cast(input_mask, tf.float32)
            pooled = masked_reduce_mean(result, input_mask)
        else:
            raise NameError(f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}")

        return pooled

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)

    def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'n_fine_tune_layers': self.n_fine_tune_layers,
            'trainable': self.trainable,
            'output_size': self.output_size,
            'pooling': self.pooling,
            'bert_path': self.bert_path,
            'dropout': self.dropout,
        })

        return config


# Build model
def build_model(max_seq_length):
    in_id = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_ids")
    in_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_masks")
    in_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="segment_ids")
    bert_inputs = [in_id, in_mask, in_segment]

    bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3)(bert_inputs)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(bert_output)
    pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense)

    # embedding_size = 768
    # bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3)(bert_inputs)
    # # Reshape bert_output before passing it the GRU
    # bert_output_ = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((max_seq_length, embedding_size))(bert_output)

    # gru_out = tf.keras.layers.GRU(100, activation='sigmoid')(bert_output_)
    # dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(gru_out)
    # pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.summary()

    return model


def initialize_vars(sess):
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    K.set_session(sess)


def main():
    # Params for bert model and tokenization
    bert_path = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"
    max_seq_length = 256

    train_df, test_df = master_df[:round(len(master_df)*.8)], master_df[round(len(master_df)*.8):]


    # Create datasets (Only take up to max_seq_length words for memory)
    train_text = train_df["words"].tolist()
    train_text = [" ".join(t.split()[0:max_seq_length]) for t in train_text]
    train_text = np.array(train_text, dtype=object)[:, np.newaxis]
    train_label = train_df["new_grouping"].tolist()

    test_text = test_df["words"].tolist()
    test_text = [" ".join(t.split()[0:max_seq_length]) for t in test_text]
    test_text = np.array(test_text, dtype=object)[:, np.newaxis]
    test_label = test_df["new_grouping"].tolist()

    # Instantiate tokenizer
    tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module(bert_path)

    # Convert data to InputExample format
    train_examples = convert_text_to_examples(train_text, train_label)
    test_examples = convert_text_to_examples(test_text, test_label)

    # Convert to features
    (
        train_input_ids,
        train_input_masks,
        train_segment_ids,
        train_labels,
    ) = convert_examples_to_features(
        tokenizer, train_examples, max_seq_length=max_seq_length
    )
    (
        test_input_ids,
        test_input_masks,
        test_segment_ids,
        test_labels,
    ) = convert_examples_to_features(
        tokenizer, test_examples, max_seq_length=max_seq_length
    )

    model = build_model(max_seq_length)

    # Instantiate variables
    initialize_vars(sess)

    checkpoint_path = "bert_dir/cp.ckpt"
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname('checkpoint_path')

    # Create a callback that saves the model's weights
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                    save_weights_only=True,
                                                    verbose=1)
    history = model.fit(
        [train_input_ids, train_input_masks, train_segment_ids],
        train_labels,
        validation_data=(
            [test_input_ids, test_input_masks, test_segment_ids],
            test_labels,
        ),
        epochs=1,
        batch_size=32,
        callbacks=[cp_callback]
    )

    model.save('bert_1.h5')


    return history

if __name__ == "__main__":
   history = main()
```

#### EDIT 1

After adding the `get_config.py` into the `BertLayer` class (See edit above), I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ac0d0189838a> in <module>()
    383 
    384 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 385    history, train_df, val_df, model = main()

6 frames
<ipython-input-11-ac0d0189838a> in main()
    377     )
    378 
--> 379     model.save('bert_1.h5')
    380 
    381 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures)
   1169     """
   1170     saving.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
-> 1171                       signatures)
   1172 
   1173   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures)
    107           'or using `save_weights`.')
    108     hdf5_format.save_model_to_hdf5(
--> 109         model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    110   else:
    111     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in save_model_to_hdf5(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
     91 
     92   try:
---> 93     model_metadata = saving_utils.model_metadata(model, include_optimizer)
     94     for k, v in model_metadata.items():
     95       if isinstance(v, (dict, list, tuple)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saving_utils.py in model_metadata(model, include_optimizer, require_config)
    155   model_config = {'class_name': model.__class__.__name__}
    156   try:
--> 157     model_config['config'] = model.get_config()
    158   except NotImplementedError as e:
    159     if require_config:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_config(self)
    884     for layer in self.layers:  # From the earliest layers on.
    885       layer_class_name = layer.__class__.__name__
--> 886       layer_config = layer.get_config()
    887 
    888       filtered_inbound_nodes = []

<ipython-input-11-ac0d0189838a> in get_config(self)
    246     def get_config(self):
    247 
--> 248         config = super(BertLayer).get_config().copy()
    249         config.update({
    250             'n_fine_tune_layers': self.n_fine_tune_layers,

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_config'
```

#### EDIT 2:

When I remove BertLayer as an argument for super() in the get_config(), the model saves. However, when I attempt to load it with tensorflow.keras.load_model, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fc5e61399702> in <module>()
      1 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
      2 
----> 3 model_ = load_model('path.h5',custom_objects={'BertLayer':BertLayer})

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    141   if (h5py is not None and (
    142       isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--> 143     return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    144 
    145   if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    160     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
    161     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
--> 162                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)
    163 
    164     # set weights

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/model_config.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
     53                     '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
     54   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 55   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
     56 
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    103       module_objects=globs,
    104       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 105       printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    189             custom_objects=dict(
    190                 list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 191                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    192       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    193         return cls.from_config(cls_config)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1069     # First, we create all layers and enqueue nodes to be processed
   1070     for layer_data in config['layers']:
-> 1071       process_layer(layer_data)
   1072     # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.
   1073     # Nodes that cannot yet be processed (if the inbound node

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in process_layer(layer_data)
   1053       from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize as deserialize_layer  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   1054 
-> 1055       layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
   1056       created_layers[layer_name] = layer
   1057 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    103       module_objects=globs,
    104       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 105       printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    191                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    192       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
--> 193         return cls.from_config(cls_config)
    194     else:
    195       # Then `cls` may be a function returning a class.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in from_config(cls, config)
    599         A layer instance.
    600     """
--> 601     return cls(**config)
    602 
    603   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

<ipython-input-4-7942232d57db> in __init__(self, n_fine_tune_layers, pooling, bert_path, **kwargs)
    170             )
    171 
--> 172         super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    173 
    174     def build(self, input_shape):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __init__(self, trainable, name, dtype, dynamic, **kwargs)
    298     }
    299     # Validate optional keyword arguments.
--> 300     generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
    301 
    302     # Mutable properties

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
    597   for kwarg in kwargs:
    598     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
--> 599       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'output_size')
```

#### get_config code

```
    def get_config(self):

        config = super(BertLayer, self).get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'n_fine_tune_layers': self.n_fine_tune_layers,
            'trainable': self.trainable,
            'output_size': self.output_size,
            'pooling': self.pooling,
            'bert_path': self.bert_path,
            'dropout': self.dropout,
        })

        return config
```

*However* I am able to save the model weights with `model.save_weights`. I understand that this saves the weights only and not actual model. How do I save the model? I can use `load_weights()` to load the weights, but how do I reconstruct the entire model to predict on new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you literally reconstruct the entire model, exactly the same way you constructed it for the first time. It seems `build_model` contains it entirely.

Then you do `model.load_weights(path)`.

Your approach will not save the optimizer, though. If you want to "continue" training a loaded model, you'd better have the optimizer saved.

For using `model.save` you just need to write the `get_config` method for the `BertLayer`. 
You can find a lot of examples on how to write this method by looking at how Keras writes it in its own layers:

- Dense: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L796
- Conv: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L361
- etc.: https://keras.io/layers/core/

Remember that the model loader doesn't know your layer, you have to inform it:

```
load_model(...., custom_objects={'BertLayer':BertLayer})
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I want to pursue the get_config method so I can save the whole model with model.save. I looked into your examples and tried to understand how to adapt the examples to my purpose. I edited my code to include my attempted get_config function in the BertLayer class, but I keep running into errors. Do you know where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @connor449, it's not `super()`, it's `super(BertLayer, self)`

Comment: Thanks. My get_config code reflects this and is `super()`. However, I am still getting the error in Edit 2. I am copying get_config() to its own code block so its easier to see and fix. See edits above.

Comment: But it must not be `super()`, it must be `super(BertLayer, self)`.

Comment: I tried `super(BertLayer, self)` and I got the error seen in Edit 2

Comment: Read the updated answer, you need to use `custom_objects` when loading the model.

Comment: @ Daniel Möller. I did not notice custom_objects before, thank you. I'm loading the model like you suggest and have altered the get_config code as you suggest (see updated get_config code block). However, now I get a new error, which is seen under Edit 2 referencing output_size. I've tried setting output_size directly to 768, and I've also tried commenting out output_size. Neither work and I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Now you just need to check which parameters the layer needs. If you don't use `output_size` in the initialization, it will go to the `super(...).__init__(...)`, and it won't accept parameters that it doesn't expect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was solved by limiting the get_config parameters to those included in the `__init__`.